# Does javascript STOMP client work in browser/frontend js?

Tags: java, websocket, stomp

I want to make a Java application that uses stomp over activemq and a nodejs application that serves a few webpages that will talk to each other. With events being emitted from the client webpages served up.

I know socketio comes with separately a server-side javascript and a client-side javascript API.

I see there is a node-stomp-client:
    https://github.com/easternbloc/node-stomp-client

Though it looks like it is used in server-side node instead of client-side javascript. Is this library actually usable both by server-side and clientside javascript? Or does STOMP websockets have a clientside javascript library that I can use in the frontend to connect/emit events to (say if the user clicks on a button in html that fires it off)?

Or should I instead not use a stomp library and just use a plain websocket library?

Answer (score 1):

There indeed is a [Javascript STOMP client implementation for browsers](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/) which is mentioned in [Implementations list](http://stomp.github.io/implementations.html#STOMP_Clients) that is linked to at the [`stomp` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stomp/info).